# Set up headset to use with iMac?

Tags: headphones

I just bought a bluetooth **Headset** ([this one](http://reviews.cnet.com/headsets/plantronics-savor-m1100-bluetooth/4505-13831_7-34188145.html)). I paired it with my iMac and set it as "use as audio device".

Now it works with some application but not with all applications:

```
It works fine with:
+ music played with iTunes.
+ system sounds 

It doesn't work at all with:
- online radios played with my browser (Chrome)
- Skype
```

**I want to use the headset as the device for Input and Output audio.**

Do I need to set those app (Chrome, Skype...) something like to grant permission to use the headset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the "Sound" preference pane to set the default input and output to use the headset and then in Skype and other apps you will also need to go to their preferences and choose the headset there.

I have had to follow the same steps with a USB connected headset.